# NFT sent from address that had not received the NFT

Tags: nft

Transaction `0xc09726f9793e2424be673308f220551ad2f6456eeacf23c49f9d437816a918c8` involves the sending of NFTs from what appears to be addresses that never received the NFTs in the first place.

For example, `0x91f6c4d8d5438bc0B76e6b8AFA9A75Ba64559483` does not have any receive of the NFT in question yet there is [a transaction of it (Etherscan link)](https://etherscan.io/token/0x17253d6344353ccc680c632d742fa113f5751b40?a=0x1bbfa7ea2740e070c80a3696b4104989907a41be) to `0x1bbfa7ea2740e070c80a3696b4104989907a41be`:

[image: Screenshot of transfer of 1 Top Kitten Officials]

So, how is this possible? Doesn't the address that sent the transaction have to own or have permission to send the NFT to take this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there actually isnt any transfer executed here, this is phishing. There are only `Transfer` events emitted, no actual NFT transfers

Comment: What does it mean that `Transfer` events were emitted?